# How to add padding/margin between icon and Up-Button of the ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-homebutton

I have to set margin of 10dp between up button and icon, 5 dp between icon and Title  in default action bar (android 4.2.2), can anyone please suggest how it can be done.

I don't want to create custom action bar as my required is exactly same as default action bar with change in height, and padding between icon, up button and title. Also change in text size.

Can this be achieved using defualt action bar. I am able to change the height of action bar.

Answer (score 4):

You can add a **padding / margin** by getting the ImageView of the icon from the ActionBar.

This is how:

```
ImageView icon = (ImageView) findViewById(android.R.id.home);
FrameLayout.LayoutParams iconLp = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) icon.getLayoutParams();
iconLp.topMargin = iconLp.bottomMargin = 0;
icon.setLayoutParams(iconLp);
```

**Edit:** Use this code for example in your Activity's `onCreate` method.

Comment: This doesnt support api10 :(

Comment: Actually it should. Whats your "error" message? What is not supported?

Comment: Yellow line below android.R.id.home and if I hover over it, I get "Field requires API level 11 (current min is 10): android.R.id#home" btw Im using sherlockactionbar

Comment: Ah yes, the ActionBar was introduced in API 10, but the home-icon an only be referenced in API 11 or higher.

Comment: so is there any way of changing that margin there?

Comment: @PhilippJahoda - In Lollipop it throws the following error `java.lang.NullPointerException:` Attempt to invoke virtual method `android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams android.widget.ImageView.getLayoutParams()` on a null object reference